# What do these questions mean?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Can someone please explain what these questions mean in simpler terms?

1)If  g is  continuous on $[a,b]$ and for all $ x ∈ [a,b] $ we have $ g(x) ≥ 0 $ and also $ g(x_o) > 0$ for some $x_o ∈ [a,b]$ then $\int_b^a g(x)dx > 0$

2) If $\int_b^a f(x)dx>0$ then there is an interval $[c,d]⊂[a,b]$ and a $δ>0$ 
such that for all $x ∈ [c,d]$ we have $f(x) ≥ δ$

Comment: Is $f$ continuous? Is this Riemann integration?

Comment: Yes it is integrable but not necessarily continuous

Comment: I presume it is Riemann integration, as $f = 1_{\mathbb{Q}^c}$ would be an immediate counterexample otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For number one, it's saying that if a continuous function is never negative and actually rises above the axis to hit a positive number somewhere, then there must be a positive area between the graph of the function and the $x$-axis.

Think about continuous functions, they can hit a point above the axis $f(x_0)>0$ only if they rise above zero for a whole interval surrounding $x_0$.

Comment: $f$ wasn't presumed continuous in 2).

Comment: @copper.hat We have to assume that was an oversight because otherwise it is not even true...

Comment: @GregoryGrant: If it is Riemann integration, it is true.

Comment: Okay thanks! I also have the solution but I don't quite understand the solution as well but il try.

Comment: @GPerez OK I removed the comment.